# How to show divs one by one after click().next() using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-selectors

I have a list structure like this:

```
  <ul id="part">   
    <?php 
      $i=0; 
      foreach ($q as  &$value):
        $i++;
        $quid = $value->q_id;
        $ans= $this->mem->get_ans($quid);
        echo '<li id="div'.$i.'" class="ques" style="display: none;">';
        echo '  <h2>'.$i.' . '.$value->question.'</h2>';              
                foreach($ans as $answer):
                  echo '<label>';
                  echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$answer->ans_id.'" />';
                  echo $answer->ans_name;
                  echo '</label>';
                endforeach;
        echo '</li>';
      endforeach; ?>
      <button id="next">Next</button>
    </ul>
```

I want the following: When someone clicks the button `#next`, then it will show the next list item and further on. How can I achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: You have a [tag:jquery] ([tag:javascript]) question; this is client-side. [tag:php] is server-side, and therefore (almost entirely) irrelevant to this question. Please post the actual (or representative) html mark-up of your page in order that we can (better) help you.

Comment: @David `<ul id="part"> <li>...</li> ... <li></li> </ul>`

Comment: Please edit that *into* the *question*, where it's more readily visible to those wanting to answer. But thank you for providing some code! =)

Comment: Btw, having your button inside the `<ul>` without an `<li>` is invalid markup :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<button>` tag outside of `<ul>` only `<li>` (list items) are valid inside an unordered list.

The JavaScript (using jQuery) needed to do what you are asking is below:

```
$(function() {

    //cache the items for quicker access       
    var items = $('ul#part li');

    //bind your event to #next
    $('#next').click(function() {

       //Check if no elements are visible yet.
       if(items.filter(':visible').length == 0) {
         items.first().show();
       }
       else {
         //Otherwise, select the last visible one, 
         //then transverse to the next one and show it
         items.filter(':visible:last').next().show();
       }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this method to show the list item one by one

```
     $(function(){             

  var i=2;
    $("#div1").show("slow");
     $('#next').click(function(){
         $('#div' + i).show('slow');
         var j=i-1;
         $('#div'+ j).hide('slow');
        i++;

     });


  });

         });
```